# How can I be sure a general purpose register is not being used by others before entering a inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

Below is a piece of GCC inline assembly code. It increases the input `*Value` by one in an atomic fashion. And return the increased value.

In the assembly code, it uses the `EAX` register. How can I know `EAX` is not being used by others before this function is called? If it is being used, the assembly code will corrupt something.

```
UINT32
__cdecl
AtomicIncrement (
  IN      volatile UINT32    *Value
  )
{
  UINT32  Result;

  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl    $1, %%eax  \n\t" ; <============== HERE, EAX is being modified.
    "lock               \n\t"
    "xadd    %%eax, %2  \n\t"
    "inc     %%eax          "
    : "=a" (Result),          // %0
      "=m" (*Value)           // %1
    : "m"  (*Value)           // %2
    : "memory",
      "cc"
    );

  return Result;
}
```

I read from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) that:

> ...Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX
>   register...  (the cdecl call convention)

So does it mean that if I follow the `cdecl` call convention, the compiler will make sure the `EAX` can be **safely used** when entering an assembly function? If I use some other general purpose register, say `EBX`, I **must** put it in the [clobber section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)? I.e. after the last colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an `"=a"` output operand, so the compiler knows that your asm writes that register.

It will plan accordingly, using a different register for anything it wants to still have after your asm runs.  It's up to you to accurately describe your asm to the compiler with constraints, because it's a black box otherwise.

Function calling conventions have basically zero relevance for inline asm. 
 After this function inlines, it will be in the middle of some larger function.

---

There is no benefit to doing this with inline asm instead of GNU C builtin `__atomic_add_fetch`, which will compile to `lock xadd` or `lock add` depending on whether the result is used or not.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html.

If you do insist on using inline asm, use a `"+r"` and a `"+m"` constraint for the two input/output operands and *just* have `lock xadd` inside the asm template.  Let the compiler do the rest, so write that in C (setting the register input to `1` before the asm, and incrementing it after).  That lets the compiler optimize the `++` into some later operation if it wants.  GCC knows how to put `1` in a register, and how to increment.

Of course, gcc also knows how to use `lock`ed instructions, which is why you should let it do so by using builtins, or C++11 std::atomic.

Comment: However there is no early clobber modifier so the compiler may use the same register for the input operand

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin: good point; the memory operand could be using an addressing mode like `(%rax)`, so that's another danger separate from the one the OP was asking about.  That's another benefit to doing what I recommended and having only the `lock xadd` inside the inline asm, if you use inline asm at all.  Doing the `mov` and `inc` with inline asm is potentially optimization-defeating as well as dangerous.